Socket.io slow to reconnect after server restart
When I restart my socket.io process (nodejs behind nginx proxy), the server refuse most of the connections attempt for the first few minutes.
When looking at the log, it looks like it accept connections one by one, I see my players slowly getting connected, but it's random and sometimes it takes 2 minute for a client to get its socket connected.

It's not a client config issue as I see in my network the connection attempts to the server right away.
The server is started and ready in 5 seconds, so it's not that either (some lucky players are getting re-connected right away)
Once a few minute has passed, the issue does not happens again before a new process restart,
I do not have I/O blocking code, everything is in async function (socket events).
Using socket.io 4.7.2
